# Magento 1.9 recaptcha validation failed error

Tags: magento-1.9, recaptcha, failed

We have a module which enables reaptcha.I have it running on my magento 1.9.
The form works fine generated form the module. but some of the customer says they get "RECAPTCHA VALIDATION FAILED" error.
I dont know what must be the cause. there are no logs.

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you how RECAPTCHA validation works in Magento, RECAPTCHA is loaded on client browser, human user is confirmed & when RECAPTCHA check is successfully completed on browser end, it sets a flag field in form and this flag field is checked on server for RECAPTCHA validation.

It seems in your case the RECAPTCHA is not completely loaded on client browser hence no flag is set but the server validation is expecting for RECAPTCHA field. So it throws the error.

Possible reason for RECAPTCHA not getting loaded on client browser could be

1. Some JS is restricting RECAPTCHA from getting loaded.
2. CORS policy - This happens when user is browsing your website with `http` but the RECAPTCHA url is with `https` or vice versa.

In my case it was 2nd option.

Hope it helps.
Thanks